# Web scraping in Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape the data of information about new properties in real estate for a project.

I get an error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

when I try to get the number of beds from the web. I am able to get other attributes not only bedroom.

link: - https://www.99acres.com/search/property/buy/residential-all/ahmedabad-all?search_type=QS&refSection=GNB&search_location=NRI&lstAcn=NR_R&lstAcnId=-1&src=CLUSTER&preference=S&selected_tab=1&city=45&res_com=R&property_type=R&isvoicesearch=N&keyword_suggest=Ahmedabad%20(All)%3B&fullSelectedSuggestions=Ahmedabad%20(All)&strEntityMap=W3sidHlwZSI6ImNpdHkifSx7IjEiOlsiQWhtZWRhYmFkIChBbGwpIiwiQ0lUWV80NSwgUFJFRkVSRU5DRV9TLCBSRVNDT01fUiJdfV0%3D&texttypedtillsuggestion=ahme&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&suggestion=CITY_45%2C%20PREFERENCE_S%2C%20RESCOM_R&searchform=1&price_min=null&price_max=null

Here's my code:

```
titles = []
prices = []
super_area = []
bhk = []
move = []
for post in item:
    title = post.find(id='srp_tuple_property_title').get_text().strip()
    price = post.find(id='srp_tuple_price').get_text().strip()
    area = post.find(id='srp_tuple_primary_area').get_text().strip()
    moves = post.find(class_='badges__secondaryLargeSubtle').get_text().strip()
    bed = post.find(id='srp_tuple_bedroom').get_text().strip()
    bhk.append(bed)
    move.append(moves)
    super_area.append(area)
    prices.append(price)
    titles.append(title)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the underlying API. Inspecting the actual API call after filtering will give you the right URL.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.99acres.com/api-aggregator/project/searchWidget?area_unit=1&platform=DESKTOP&moduleName=GRAILS_SRP&workflow=GRAILS_SRP&city=45&preference=S&res_com=R&page=1&page_size=10&isCrossSell=false"
data = requests.get(url=url).json()
print(data['newProjects'][1]['propTypeStr'])
# 2 BHK Apartment
```

Filtering will change the parameters of the URL, for example:

```
https://www.99acres.com/api-aggregator/srp/search?bedroom_num=3&budget_min=136&locality_array=6046%2C6038&area_min=1900&area_unit=1&localityNameMap=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&platform=DESKTOP&moduleName=GRAILS_SRP&workflow=GRAILS_SRP&page_size=30&page=1&city=45&preference=S&res_com=R&seoUrlType=DEFAULT
```

This can be broken down with `urllib`:

```py
from urllib import parse

url = "https://www.99acres.com/api-aggregator/srp/search?bedroom_num=3&budget_min=136&locality_array=6046%2C6038&area_min=1900&area_unit=1&localityNameMap=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&platform=DESKTOP&moduleName=GRAILS_SRP&workflow=GRAILS_SRP&page_size=30&page=1&city=45&preference=S&res_com=R&seoUrlType=DEFAULT"
parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(url).query)
# {'bedroom_num': ['3'],
#  'budget_min': ['136'],
#  'locality_array': ['6046,6038'],
#  'area_min': ['1900'],
#  'area_unit': ['1'],
#  'localityNameMap': ['[object Object]'],
#  'platform': ['DESKTOP'],
#  'moduleName': ['GRAILS_SRP'],
#  'workflow': ['GRAILS_SRP'],
#  'page_size': ['30'],
#  'page': ['1'],
#  'city': ['45'],
#  'preference': ['S'],
#  'res_com': ['R'],
#  'seoUrlType': ['DEFAULT']}
```